# Why can't you pass an instance of Collections as function paramerter in Java?

Tags: c#, java

Let's say I've a function as follows:

```
private void check(HashSet<String> input)
{
}
```

The function call I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
check(new HashSet<String>value("test"));
```

This is not allowed in Java. There's no definition for this in Java.

Now I know that same thing I can do in C# like this:

```
String[] val={"test"};
check(new HashSet<String>(val));
```

I would like to know why is it like this. In Java I can pass a Integer in that manner. E.g

```
test(new Integer(3));
```

While this is not possible in C# for integer/Int32.

**I'm trying to think why this design decisions were taken. Are there benefits of this approaches?**

I'm trying to understand why a particular aspect of a language is the way it is? Please don't point out syntax error of using Array. asList()

Comment: This questions is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what is HashSet<String>value("test") ??? Did you test and find out if it works?

Comment: @Jeff Why is it better suited and if so can I migrate it?

Comment: Your `HashSet` examples are not equivalent in C# and Java , as you are initializing your C# `HashSet` with an array of `string`, and an array is an `IEnumerable` type in C#. Your java example passes a string to the constructor, when you really are expected to pass a collection. You could still use a `String`, and then use `Arrays.asList()` on it to use it in `HashSet` construction.

Comment: in Java you can use specialized libs such as: Google Guava Sets<String>.newHashSet("aaa")

Comment: Your question si Wrong, completely wrong!!

Comment: @gizgok Per the FAQs of both sites, http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq, SO is about practical, answerable problems and Programmers is more about theoretical questions.

Comment: You can use a literal array in Java, the syntax is actually exact as in C#:

    `check(new HashSet<String>(new string[] { "test" }));`

Using `new Integer(3)` in Java is a different matter. Java has object wrappers for the primitive types, while C# uses boxing instead. If the method takes a parameter of the type `Object`, you can just pass the integer value `3` and it will automatically be boxed. If you need to specifically box a value type, you use the casting syntax:

    `test((object)3);`

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing wrong in your code is the syntax... The closest syntax I can think of is:

```
new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList(new String[]{"test"}));
```

Which basiclly means:

1.- Create an array containing only one string

```
new String[]{"test"}
```

2.- Wrap the array in a list

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"test"})
```

3.- Initialize a HashSet of Strings with the wrapped array in the list (unfortunately HashSet only takes instances of collections, and array is not an instance of a collection... Also, only arrays can be initialized inline in java)

```
new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList(new String[]{"test"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap constructor doesnt accept a String, it accepts a collection in java. So try this

new HashSet(Arrays.asList("test"));

Answer (score 0):

You want to create sigleton map. Do it as following: `Collections.singleton("test")`.
But change the method prototype definition to

`private void check(Set<String> input)`

It is always better to use interfaces when possible than concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you understand wrong, in java you can pass an instance of Collections as a function parameter but you have at least to **write it correctly**!!

This would work:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    private static void check(HashSet<String> input)
    {
    }

    public static void main (String []args) {
        check(new HashSet<String>());
    }
}
```